# VBA Text-To-Columns Reading Date Format As US

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

When running text-to-columns in vba, it puls my dates as american dates, instead of uk dates, as long as it is possible for it to do so. So for example, 31-Aug stays as 31-Aug, but 01-Sep changes to 09-Jan!

Is there any way to specify that all dates are in UK format BEFORE vba runs? As even just reformatting to US dates to show as US dates won't work because we have code that runs `if date < Today`, which of course will cause issues with the changing date format.

The data feeds in the format dd/mm/yyyy, but excel reads it as mm/dd/yyyy!

Comment: You need to specify the correct format in the FieldInfo argument. Still not 100% reliable because VBA is extremely US-centric but it's the only option if you use TextToColumns.

Comment: @Rory i'm pretty sure FieldInfo doesn't work for UK dates, I know FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4) should work, but it just ignores it and does it ans US anyway

Answer (score 1):

pnuts comment is the easiest method to solve this problem.

Explanation:

Run the 'Record Macro', select your column and initiate text-to-columns wizard.

On the 3rd page of the text-to-columns wizard, under 'Column data format', the 'Date' option is automatically set to 'MDY'. Change this to 'DMY'.

Stop the macro and you will find this code

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A:A"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

The "4" in `=Array(1,4)` is the part that determines DMY format.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? because I think there is a bug that makes this ineffective in VBA.  Works perfectly in excel, but in VBA your code above will format to US dates every time.  It does the same thing in reverse, so if you have Uk dates (as dates) and you try to use texttocolumns to make them text, they all come out as US format. It seems in VBA the texttocolumns function only works in US format.

Comment: This answer helped me solve my issue.  If you edit the recorded macro to your requirements.  The statement 'Array(1,2)' specifies column = 1 and the xlcolumndatatype = 2, choose the appropriate columndatatype using the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolumndatatype

Answer (score 1):

I have came up with a hack way to solve it. I change the format from dates to text, then I use TextToColumns and finally return the format to dates.

```vb
Sub DMYFormat(rng as Range)
    rng.NumberFormat = @
    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng.EntireColumn, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, xlDMYFormat), TrailingMinusNumbers
    rng.NumberFormat = d/m/yyyy
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me too as I had the problem that Tom described below: some of my rows had actual dates and some had text dates. So flipping everything to text first, then converting with TextToColumns and finally applying the Date format left me with all rows with dates.

Comment: I have noticed an error in my code. The text may be read as text. So I changed them back into *text* with the correct format (d/m/yyyy in this case) solved my issue. May change it later.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set the language first with Application.International?

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840213(v=office.15).aspx][1]

Comment: This is for 2013 and 2010, I'm using 2007 :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a workarround for this case. First get the date part from the text before doing TexttoColumn. This date will be in text. Use Left, Mid and right functions to get the date, month and year and then use the function dateserial in vba with these arguments. Now you will get 2 type of dates. Date in text format which will be in UK format which you can store in the cells in excel. Other is in UK format which will be used on for **if date < Today** condition. U can now use text to columns and ignore the date that comes from texttocolumns and use date as text instead. The code for same in mentioned below for eg - "31/08/2014 part1 part2"

```
Sub t() 

Dim myarr() As String

Dim cell As Range

  For Each cell In Selection ' selection contains cells which text you need to convert text to columns
      i = i + 1
      myarr = Split(cell.Value, " ")
      mydate = Val(Left(myarr(0), 2))
      mymonth = Val(Mid(myarr(0), InStr(1, myarr(0), "/") + 1, 2))
      myyear = Val(Right(myarr(0), 4))
      date_american = DateSerial(myyear, mymonth, mydate)
      date_uk = myarr(0)
  Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a better option. Define the column as text so:

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A:A"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Using the 2 format creates a text field so there will be no formating.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same issue today, I too used the DMY in text to columns which worked when when doing it manually but in VBA as described above always changes to US data format where possible.

I got around this (which may not be suitable for you) by inserting a new column to the right and using =TEXT(Cell, "DD/MM/YYYY") and then copying and pasting the values.

I deleted the original column afterwards, I also ensure this always works regardless of the amount of rows by working out my last row with data in each time.

VBA segments below..

```
Sub Dateformat()

'sets i as last current row with data in

    Dim i As Integer

    Range("A2").Select

    i = ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row

    Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-1],""DD/MM/YYYY"")"
Selection.Copy
Range("D2:D" & i).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this observation is helpful (Excel365 64bit):

Conclusion:
Be careful to apply TextToColumn ONLY to cells that actually contain text formatted dates and NOT to cells are already recognized as dates by Excel.

Observation:
I used VBA to fill cells with data from an array containing dates using "range.value =".
The result will be cells filled with the data in text format (e.g. 01.09.2019 is in the cell, but Excel doesn't know it is a date for 1. Sept. 2019 but only sees text).
I then used VBA TextToColumns to turn those cells into actual dates specifying "FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4)". The format was indeed DMY.

This worked well BUT all things got messed up when some cells in the range were already recognized as dates by Excel.

Scenario in my case:
Data was added using "value = (dates from an arry variable)" to the bottom of a column resulting in text formatted cells. I wanted to use TextToColumn to reformat the data into dates. But TextToColumns was every time applied to the entire column containng cells that had already been reformatted previously instead of only the newly added data.

Here is what happened:
For some reason VBA read the already date format cell correctly but then switched around month and day where possible to write them back as MDY. To see what I mean you can try applying TextToColumns to date format cells using "FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)". 01.09.2019 for 1. Sept. 2019 will be turned into a text cell with "09/01/2019" for 9. January 2019.

We therefore have to be careful to apply TextToColumn ONLY to really text formatted data when writing back in date format. A possible work around may be to somehow first read the entire data into an array and write it back to ensure that all data is of the same format to start with.

Comment: The solution above from "The unknown". That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for an answer, but I run into the same issue (in Excel 2019) and after several try/catch cycles, finally nailed it.

As an example, having this plain text with dates in DMY format (single line):

```
03/12/2022 05:58:49 p. m.   info    192.168.XX.X
    connect     03/12/2022 06:07:18 p. m.   info    disconnect
```

the answer for me was replacing all occurences of "a. m." and "p. m." by "AM" and "PM", splitting in columns without format, in plain text:

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlTextFormat), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), _
    Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, xlTextFormat), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

After all the process, deleting several useless columns, ended with the connect timestamp in column A and the disconnect timestamp in column B.

Final step, convert that text into a proper date field:

```
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DATE(MID(RC[-2], 7, 4), MID(RC[-2], 4, 2), " & _
    "MID(RC[-2], 1, 2)) + TIMEVALUE(MID(RC[-2], 12, 11))"
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DATE(MID(RC[-2], 7, 4), MID(RC[-2], 4, 2), " & _
    "MID(RC[-2], 1, 2)) + TIMEVALUE(MID(RC[-2], 12, 11))"
```

Plus what I really needed, that was the time connected:

```
Range("E1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"
```

Must keep columns A and B? Yes. Wasn't really important at this point, since I wouldn't save it, just needed for a time period calculation. Just hid them for an aesthetic view

Tried Barry suggestion, but querying Application.International(xlDateOrder) returns 1, which is, according the documentation, DMY:

*xlDateOrder    Long    Order of date elements: 0 = month-day-year, 1 = day-month-year, 2 = year-month-day*

Hope this help somebody.

Regards.
Gustavo.